# problems in verb stemming in python

Tags: python

I want to find stems of verbs. I put the suffixes that I want to delete in a variable. the problem is that it just deletes the first item in the list and doesn't for the rest of the items and returns the verb without stemming. How should I change it that it can read all the items in the list?

```
def stemming (verb):
    suffix=["ing", "ed", "es", "s"]
    for i in suffix:
        stem=verb.replace(i, "")
        return stem
        i+=1

>>> stemming ("wanting")
'want'
>>> stemming ("wanted")
'wanted'
```

Comment: You don't need the `i+=1` either. `i` is one of the elements of the list `suffix`, not an index.

Comment: As soon as you make the changes everyone's suggesting here, try `stemming('singing')` and puzzle out why your algorithm produces an empty string as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as your function returns, it is finished. It doesn't carry on going through the loop replacing more stuff. I think what you actually want is something more like this:

```
def stemming(verb):
    suffixes = ["ing", "ed", "es", "s"]
    for suffix in suffixes:
        if verb.endswith(suffix):
            return verb[:-len(suffix)]
    return verb
```

So it actually checks if the verb ends in each suffix, and doesn't return unless it finds one that does.

Answer (score 4):

Because you `return` too early. The very moment Python encounters a `return` inside a closing function; it **will** return immediately to the callee (*the function that called `stemming`*).

Change your function `stemming` to:

```
def stemming (verb):
    suffixs = ["ing", "ed", "es", "s"]
    for suffix in suffixs:
        stem = verb.replace(suffix, "")
    return stem  # XXX: Moving the return outside of the loop
```

You also do not need to increment `i` here; it's not even an integer anyway; you're iterating over a list of strings. Each iteration over `suffixes` (*I renamed some variables to be more readable*) will in turn be the strings as specified in the list.

---

If you *really* wanted to use a counter variant to index `suffixes`:

```
def stemming (verb):
    suffixs = ["ing", "ed", "es", "s"]
    i = 0
    while i < len(suffixes):
        stem = verb.replace(suffixs[i], "")
        i += 1
    return stem
```

**However**; this is really unnecessary as you can just use normal and more Pythonic iteration over the list: `for suffix in suffixes:`

---

I also believe your function is also meant to be:

Code:

```
def stemming(verb):
    suffixs = ["ing", "ed", "es", "s"]
    for suffix in suffixs:
        verb = verb.replace(suffix, "")
    return verb
```

Output:

```
>>> stemming("singing")
''
```

Think about it! :)

---

Also as an aside; you *really* should be using [nltk](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk) for stemming anyway unless you are just doing this for educational purposes.

See: [`nltk.stem`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html)

**Example:**

```
>>> from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
>>> st = LancasterStemmer()
>>> st.stem("singing")
'sing'  # NOT an empty string!!!
>>> st.stem("wanting")
'want'
>>> st.stem("wanted")
'want'
```

Answer (score 3):

Move return out of the loop and remove `i += 1`. It is useless here:

```
def stemming(verb):
    suffix=["ing", "ed", "es", "s"]
    for i in suffix:
        verb=verb.replace(i, "")
    return verb
```

Answer (score 2):

You put the return statement inside the loop, that creates the wrong behavior. I think you meant something like that:

```
def stemming (verb):
    suffix=["ing", "ed", "es", "s"]
    stem = verb
    for i in suffix:
        stem=stem.replace(i, "")
    return stem
```

I also removed the i++, which is in deed useless. The other thing of course is, that you must operate always on the same variable to catch all the changes (either stem or verb -- I used stem for more clarity, but you can also use verb and get rid of the assignment).

As one commentator pointed out, your algorithm produces some weird behavior on some verbs.

**I would suggest to change it this way:**

```
def stemming (verb):
    suffixes = ["ing", "ed", "es", "s"]
    stem = verb
    for suffix in suffixes:
        if stem.endswith(suffix):
            stem = stem[:-len(suffix)]
            break
    return stem
```

With this change, only one suffix should be removed (because of the break) and also the removal will only take place at the end of the verb.

Answer (score 1):

`return` will always end the function and return to where you called it. Use [yield](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) instead of `return` if you want to generate multiple values.

As a side note, remove your incrementation of `i` because `i` is not an integer in your code.